# Prove that $T-\sqrt{2}I$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T \in L(V)$ is such that $\|Tv\| \leq \|v\|, \forall v \in V$. Prove that $T-\sqrt{2}I$ is invertible.

I know that I need to show there exists a $R^{-1}(T-\sqrt{2}I) = I$ where $R = T-\sqrt{2}I$. I have no idea what else to do, help?

Comment: What is $V$?${}$

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional?

Comment: @copper.hat I believe this problem is from "Linear Algebra Done Right" 2nd edition by Axler. In the problem finite dimensionality is not assumed. Is it possible to show this without Banach spaces and finite dimensionality ? Given this is an intro to linear algebra book.

Comment: @dylan7: I believe you need completeness to conclude that the inverse exists. So, either finite dimensions or Banach...

Comment: @copper.hat hmm... ok thanks! Might be a mistake in the book then.

Comment: @dylan7: I would suspect that the book deals with finite dimensions?

Comment: @copper.hat it mostly does, but the section that problem is in just talks about inner product spaces, and it doesn't state that the spaces are finite dimensional. The book always explicitly states if the space is finite dimensional. Unless this question was an exception, and the person solving it was supposed to realize that? It would be the only question in the book I saw that does this, and this is chapter 6. There are always a few problems that ask the person to check the infinite dimensional case, although they are rare problems.

Comment: The chaper also stated that $V$ just stands for an inner product space, not necessarily finite dimensional. It always defines the notation it uses in the chapters.

Comment: @dylan7: I am a little surprised that completeness is not mentioned.

Comment: @copper.hat yeah, maybe the OP can attest to this as well. (@Soaps)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question can be rephrased as to show that $\sqrt2$ is not an eigenvalue for $T$. If it were, then there would be a corresponding eigenvector $v$, with $Tv=\sqrt 2\,v$. So for such $v$ you would have
$$
\|Tv\|=\|\sqrt2\,v\|=\sqrt2\,\|v\|>\|v\|,
$$
contradicting the given inequality.

**Edit:** this answer uses in an essential way the fact that $V$ is assumed finite-dimensional. The question still has an answer in the more general case of Banach spaces, as one can see from copper hat's answer.

Comment: Of course. And your answer is way better than mine. But the question is tagged "linear algebra", so the more elementary argument is enough.

Comment: In finite dimensions your answer is more direct.

Comment: @Jonas: point taken.

Comment: To be fair, this is essentially correct, depending on what OP means by "invertible", since injective functions are invertible over their range.

Answer (score 4):

Generally in a Banach space, if $\|A\| < 1$, then $I+A$ is invertible
(consider $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k A^k$).

Consider the invertibility of $I - {1 \over \sqrt{2}} T$ (what $A$ matrix, and why does it have suitable operator norm?)

Explicitly:
We have $R = T-\sqrt{2} I = -\sqrt{2}(I-{1 \over \sqrt{2}} T) $.

Let $S = - {1 \over \sqrt{2}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( {1 \over \sqrt{2}}\right)^k T_k$. Multiplying will show that $SR=I$, that is, $S = R^{-1}$.

Comment: @SpamIAm: Thanks for catching that!